# Recording a Screenscast a webinar?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, screen-capture

What are some good options for recording a screenscast or webinar?  Often, but not always, they are delivered by goto meeting and are quite often put on during horribly inconvenient times for our office.  Are there simple software that would let us record these on our mac and watch later.  Sort of like Tivo'ing them!

Answer (score 2):

Quicktime makes movie recordings and is free / included with all Mac OS X. From your requirements I would start there and ask again if you run into issues.

Answer (score 0):

[Screenflow](http://www.telestream.net/screenflow/overview.htm) works well for this, with some **serious caveats**:

1. If it runs out of hard drive space during the recording, you may lose the whole thing and also have to deal with OSX complaining until some space is freed
2. You will have to find another way to make sure the computer is on and start the recording at the right time
3. Many online meetings will require you to make some action when it's time in order to join the group

Thankfully, there are **some built-in solutions** that can be used to deal with these:

1. Screenflow is actually very good with disk usage; if there is audio and slides, it's possible to get a full sized 1 hour of recording under 500MB. For recording video, shrink the size of the window showing the video, and this will greatly reduce the file size.
2. & 3. Automator and applescript are just two of the ways to schedule, launch, do an action, and then shut everything down at the end. A very simple workflow would be: Have the meeting screen ready, verify that Screenflow is running, then schedule a script that wakes up the computer at the right time, presses command-shift-2 (start recording), waits 90 minutes, presses command-shift-2 again, and sleeps the computer.